# Return a Q Promise from an API Properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I am developing an API that I would to return a promise.  The returned promise is composed of several other promises, so I'm using Q.all and/or Q.allSettled.  The problem I'm running into is that the code never completes (see test).

I'm expecting to be able to call then/fail/etc on what's being return from addUsers, which is a Q.all or Q.allSettlted

API:

```
'use strict';

var Q = require('q'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    User = require('../models/user'),
    _ = require('underscore');


var addUsers = function (users) {
    var promises = _.map(users, function (user) {
        var newUser = new User(user);
        var promise = Q.nbind(newUser.save, newUser);
        return promise();
    });

    return Q.allSettled(promises);
};

module.exports.addUsers = addUsers;
```

Test:

```
'use strict';

var kraken = require('kraken-js'),
    express = require('express'),
    request = require('supertest'),
    should = require('chai').should(),
    userApi = require('../lib/userApi'),
    User = require('../models/user');

describe('#userApi tests', function() {

    it('should insert an array of users using the userApi addUsers method', function(done) {
        var users = [];
        var user1 = {
            firstName: 'test1',
            lastName: 'test1',
            password: 'abc123',
            email: 'me1@here.com',
            userName: 'test1'
        };
        var user2 = {
            firstName: 'test2',
            lastName: 'test2',
            password: 'abc123',
            email: 'me2@here.com',
            userName: 'test2'
        };
        var user3 = {
            firstName: 'test3',
            lastName: 'test3',
            password: 'abc123',
            email: 'me3@here.com',
            userName: 'test3'
        };
        users.push(user1);
        users.push(user2);
        users.push(user3);

        //call the api and handle the promise that is returned
        userApi.addUsers(users)
            .then(function(results) {
                should.exist(results);
                //other assumptions here
                done();
            })
            .fail(function(err) {
                done(err);
            })
    });
});
```

Comment: "Never completes" - what happens instead?

Comment: done() is the callback used to tell the test that it is complete (see the end of the it('should..');

Comment: Never completes in this instance means that neither .then nor .fail gets called, which would be normal for a promise.  E.g. somePromis.then(...);

Comment: You can return promises from Mocha now by the way. No need for that ugly done wrap.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan of `q`. I think is too much magic, so I rather use the native (on node@0.11.x) `Promise` instead.

But if I understood it right, `q.nbind` is a wrapper around the node's standard function call.
Maybe I would mimic its behavior using the new promise API as something like this.

```
promise = function () {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    newUser.save(function(err, data){
      if (err) return reject(err)
      resolve(data)

    })
  })
}
```

I'm assuming that the `newUser` is a mongoose model, and `newUSer.save` only call the callback with an error parameter. Since `data` is undefined, maybe `q` doesn't call resolve with a falsy value.

I would try running your tests with this version of `addUsers` instead.

```
var Promise = Promise || require('es6-promise').Promise // polyfill
, mongoose = require('mongoose')
;

function addUsers (users) {
  return Promise.all(users.map(function(user){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      var newUser = new User(user)
      ;
      newUser.save(function(err){
        if (err) return reject(err)
        resolve()
      })
    })
  }))
}
```

On the side, It looks like that the cool kids are using `bluebird` this days for their promise fix.
It has great error handling (which is a problem with the native promise) and allow for custom builds.

Comment: No, Q works just the same way - and it does resolve even if you pass no arguments. Your use of native promises actually looks like too less magic, with all those repetitive callbacks. `nbind` is there for a reason :-)

Comment: The reason I nested like this was to avoid creating variables. With this code, I would only save the most inner indentation with `nbind`.

Comment: Well, it's still two levels of indentation more than the OP has (`Promise()` and `save()` callbacks). Btw, you could eliminate the `newUser` variable as well.